# jQuery Function fadeTo() on all divs

Tags: jquery, extend

I'm trying to achieve an effect where I fade in all of the specified divs, one-by-one. I wrote this function:

**jQuery:**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fadeAll = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.fadeAll.defaults, options || {});

        var loops = $(this).length;

        return $(this).each(function (i, obj) {            
            $(obj).fadeTo(options.speed, options.opacity);

            if (i++ >= loops) {
                if (typeof (options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                    options.onComplete.call();
                }
            }
            //alert($(obj).html());
        });
    };

    $.fn.fadeAll.defaults = {
        speed:      300,
        opacity:    1,
        onComplete: null
    };
})(jQuery);
```

In the each loop I put an alert to watch it loop through all of my objects, which it is doing just fine when I call it like so

**Calling the function:**

```
$('.nav-div').fadeAll({
    onComplete:
        function () {
            alert('done');
        }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
</head>
<body>
    <section id="global-wrapper">
        <section id="load-wrapper">
            <div>
                <h1>LOADING</h1>
                <h3 id="load-percent"></h3>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="main-wrapper">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
            <nav>
                <div class="nav-div">MENU ITEM 1</div>
                <div class="nav-div">MENU ITEM 2</div>
                <div class="nav-div">MENU ITEM 3</div>
                <div class="nav-div">MENU ITEM 4</div>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #000;
    color: #eee;
}

#global-wrapper {
    min-height: 2000px;
}

#load-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 65%;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 17.5%;
}
    #load-wrapper > div {
        background: url('/Content/Images/loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
        #load-wrapper > div > h1 {
            font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica', serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #eee;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
        }
        #load-wrapper > div > h3 {
            font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica', serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #eee;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

#main-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
    #main-wrapper > h1 {
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica', serif;
    }
    #main-wrapper > nav > div {
        opacity: 0;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
        font-family: Gruppo;
        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

All of my callbacks are working like expected, everything is firing off. However, my issue is that while it's going through the loop, it's not actually doing the fadeTo part; rather, it waits until it's finished going through the loop then they all fade in at once.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing incorrectly here? I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing or just some functionality of jQuery/js that I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2aT4/) for it, but when should it fade out? I don't see any event in your code.

Comment: I don't want it to fade out, it's just fading in menu items one by one to give it a nice effect on page load.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood, that means the items have an opacity of 0 at page load? Isn't defined anywhere I think. I'll see and try what I can do

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't include my CSS, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a  delay see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/U2aT4/7/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.nav-div').hide();
    delay=0;
    $('.nav-div').each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(1000);
        delay += 1500;

    });

});
```

Comment: Very nice solution, maybe you could change it that it fits into the plugin from the OP?

Comment: This did it! I incorporated delay into the function I was writing and that got it to work. Thanks a ton!

Comment: better would be to make a recursive function using the build in callback from fadeIn. this needs little more thinking ...

Comment: Here's how I incorporated it. http://jsfiddle.net/U2aT4/9/ I'm not sure I follow you on your last comment, could you elaborate more on what you mean?

Comment: I mean that you could use the callback from the fadeIn event like so (pseudo code) (div).fadeIn('slow', function(){ (next_div).fadeIn(and so on)}); If you think about it you could make this recursive... wrap everything in a function and call this function in the function itself. However this need some thinking :-(